# Linq query to filter id inside a list of list c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, observable

I have a list of result List where it contains List inside of it.I have another list where it contains List alone.I want to filter using a linq query from the data where it should return all the data which  contains skill id  from the second list.

```
var list = this._viewModel.Data.Select(T => T.SkillsList);
var filtered = item.Skills.Contains(list.Where(t=>t.ToString()).ToList();
```

from the first list it contains List of decimals inside the skill list;
item.Skills contains list where the fields are skillid and code.
item is another object which contains the skillslist.

Comment: What do you want?  What?

Comment: I want to filter using a linq query from the data where it should return all the data wchich contains skill id from the second list.

Comment: Okay that's easy...  1 sec

Comment: Please post your data structure.  for Data, Skill and whatever data structure SkillsList is

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if skillId is a variable and assuming that SkillsList contains a property called Id.  Then the following would work in getting you any data that has the specified skillId.

```
var list = this._viewModel.Data.Where(t=>t.SkillsList.Any(s=>s.Id == skillId));
```

If Skillslist is just an array of integers then the following would work.

```
var list = this._viewModel.Data.Where(t=>t.SkillsList.Any(s=> s == skillId));
```

Now if you are checking against a list the following would work.

```
var list = this._viewModel.Data.Where(t=>t.SkillsList.Any(s=> skillsList.contains(s));
```

Comment: I don't think that is it...  Any?  I could be wrong but can you show the data along with the query?